# Where are Nautilus loading animation icons located?

Tags: nautilus, themes, animations

When Nautilus is loading a folder or searching for a file, there's an animation like this:

[image: Nautilus animation while loading]

How can I change it to gnome-spinner (Humanity process-working)? I’ve searched all animation directories in `/usr/share/icons/` but couldn’t find any PNG’s for such animation.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: If the Icon set you're using does not have the folder `animations` or `spinner` it defaults to the Gnome image. By the way the Gnome animation is the same as the Humanity animation which is the same as your image.

Comment: There *are* animations, but all different from that image I’ve posted. And also Humanity animation is very different. Now do you mean if I create a folder “animation” in gnome folder of icons, I will be able to change this animation?

Comment: This spinner can be for GTK-3.0, can’t it? Because Ubuntu Software Center uses similar spinner and I’ve found some lines in gtk-3.0 widgets CSS for spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the spinner in nautilus should be from gtk3, u can set it in your current themes gtk3 file, for me its `/usr/share/themes/KILLMINT/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` open it and search for string `spinner`
u will find something like this related to spinner

```
/***********
* spinner *
***********/
.menu.spinner,
.primary-toolbar .spinner,
.primary-toolbar .spinner {
color: @theme_selected_bg_color;
}

.spinner:active {
 transition: 750ms linear loop;
}
```

and try to look to other themes or distros how their spinner looks like and take the code of it (+check which engine it uses like engine=none; or engine=unico; and whether are some functions of that engine used in code of the spinner)

try code of spinner from zorin:

```
/***********
* spinner *
***********/
@keyframes spinner {
0.00% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)); }

12.5% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)); }

25.0% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)); }

37.5% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)); }

50.0% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)); }

62.5% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)); }

75.0% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)); }

87.5% { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)); }

100%  { background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.875)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.750)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.625)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.500)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.375)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.250)), to(transparent)),
                          -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(alpha(currentColor, 0.125)), to(transparent)); }
}

.spinner {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                  -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                  -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                  -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                  -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                  -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                  -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent)),
                  -gtk-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 0.5, to(currentColor), to(transparent));
background-position: 14% 14%, 0% 50%, 14% 86%, 50% 100%, 86% 86%, 100% 50%, 86% 14%, 50% 0%;
background-size: 20% 20%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.menu.spinner,
.primary-toolbar .spinner,
.primary-toolbar .spinner {
color: @selected_bg_color;
}

.spinner:active {
animation: spinner 1s infinite linear;
}
```

this will make your spinner look like made of circles, i would post a screenshot, but dont have some points(ill add em)
however gtk2 spinner will reamin the same as i didnt find how to config it, looks hard-coded somewhere but your nautilus will use those from gtk3 as my nemo does, so it shouldnt be that bad.. :D
cheers KiLLA